# How can I create a queryable alias for a foreign-key field in a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a series of models that have fields to be migrated to a FK.

**Before**

```
class Sizing(models.Model:
    btu_hour = models.IntegerField()
    flange = models.ForeignKey('parts.Router')
```

**After**

```
class Sizing(models.Model):
    btu_hour = models.IntegerField()
    configuration = models.ForeignKey(Configuration)
    ### WHAT I'D LIKE; alias only ###
    flange = Alias(to='configuration__flange')

class Configuration(models.Model)
    flange = models.ForeignKey('parts.Router')
```

Assuming I have queries in my views that do lookups on the `flange` field, how can I create an alias? I have many models that are being restructured in the manner above and would like to use this method so that I don't have to replace every use of that field in views, etc.

Would appreciate any pointers; all info on model aliases I've found only work for same-model fields.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to create a `@property`:

```
class Sizing(models.Model):
    btu_hour = models.IntegerField()
    configuration = models.ForeignKey(Configuration)

    # define the property flange
    @property
    def flange(self):
        return self.configuration.flange
```

Then, in any of the views if you have a `sizing_obj.flange` it won't be affected at all.

However, you cannot use it in queryset or filters etc.

Comment: Thanks, but seeking something that would be usable in filtering/querysets as well. Was hoping to avoid refactoring in a few dozen models but think it might be the only way.

Comment: The only entries which can be used in filtering in a queryset are the ones which are defined as a field on the model itself. In this case since you don't have a direct relationship with `Flange` objects I am not sure you can do filtering on that. The only way would be to go through the intermediate model for example here you would do `configuration__change`. I can't seem to find anything else either.

Answer (score 0):

```
aliasName = models.ForeignKey(modelName, to_field='fieldName', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is the format for aliasing in Django Foreign Key

```
class Sizing(models.Model):
    btu_hour = models.IntegerField()
    configuration = models.ForeignKey(Configuration)
    ### WHAT I'D LIKE; alias only ###
    flangeNew = models.ForeignKey(Configuration, to_field='flange', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Configuration(models.Model)
    flange = models.ForeignKey('parts.Router')
```

This is the solution of aliasing in new version of Django